# CMake : the c compiler is not able to compile a simple test program. it fails with the following output

Tags: build, cmake, mingw, codeblocks, fluidsynth

I'm trying to build fluidsynth-2.1.1 in my windows 64 bit system using CMake and MinGw but the below error is encountered:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/fluidsynth-2.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_b4b73/fast && C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_b4b73.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4b73.dir/build

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/fluidsynth-2.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4b73.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

    C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_b4b73.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\fluidsynth-2.1.1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c

    CMakeFiles\cmTC_b4b73.dir\build.make:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4b73.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4b73.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/fluidsynth-2.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

    Makefile:140: recipe for target 'cmTC_b4b73/fast' failed

    mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_b4b73/fast] Error 2

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/fluidsynth-2.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/fluidsynth-2.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

please help me find where this is going wrong.

I also disabled my antivirus

Comment: Can you check the log files (mentioned on the last two lines) if there's more information? You could also try to use that GCC to compile your own Hello World test program to see if it works outside of CMake.